# WPF hosting ActiveX control location

Tags: wpf, layout, activex

I'm hosting an ActiveX control in WPF form. It works well, no problem.
But I can't find the property that sets the location of the ActiveX control on the WPF form (in the code). So it's stuck at the center of the screen for now.

the host is a System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost

Answer (score 0):

Layout of controls in WPF is done through layout panels like Grid, StackPanel, DockPanel, etc.  They all layout the controls they contain different, so it depends on what you want. The xaml code below uses a stackpanel which layouts the controls below each other.

```
<StackPanel> 
  <WindowsFormsHost ... />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: That answers half of the problem - you just have to give the container a name, and it (and its location properties, Margin and Padding) should be accessible from the code!